# Responsive view for mobile django app working in development but not in production

Tags: python, css, django, apache, mobile

I have a blog made in django that runs on an apache server. I recently programmed the mobile view so in the template folder I have two subfolders, one for desktop and one for mobile. Each of them have their independent html template.

To automatically switch for desktop to mobile view I have in middleware.py the following:

```
from django.conf import settings
import re
reg_b = re.compile(r"(android|bb\\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino", re.I|re.M)
reg_v = re.compile(r"1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\\-(n|u)|c55\\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\\-5|g\\-mo|go(\\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\\-(m|p|t)|hei\\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\\-c|ht(c(\\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\\-|\\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\\-w|m3ga|m50\\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\\-g|qa\\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\\-[2-7]|i\\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\\-|oo|p\\-)|sdk\\/|se(c(\\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\\-|shar|sie(\\-|m)|sk\\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\\-|v\\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\\-|tdg\\-|tel(i|m)|tim\\-|t\\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\\-|m3|m5)|tx\\-9|up(\\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\\-|your|zeto|zte\\-", re.I|re.M)

class MobileTemplatesMiddleware(object):
    """Determines which set of templates to use for a mobile site"""
    ORIG_TEMPLATE_DIRS = settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS
    def process_request(self, request):
        is_mobile = False
        if request.META.has_key('HTTP_USER_AGENT'):
            user_agent = request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
            b = reg_b.search(user_agent)
            v = reg_v.search(user_agent[0:4])
            if b or v:
                is_mobile = True
        if is_mobile:
            settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS = settings.MOBILE_TEMPLATE_DIRS + self.ORIG_TEMPLATE_DIRS
        else:
            settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS = settings.DESKTOP_TEMPLATE_DIRS + self.ORIG_TEMPLATE_DIRS
```

This works in development. I get my mobile view:

[image]

However when I upload the code to the server, the mobile view is not rendered and only the desktop view is shown:

[image]

Any idea on where the problem could be???

This is the [code of the django app](https://github.com/hoaphumanoid/sciblog) on github just in case it is of any use.

Comment: Can't see the problem, but for a simple layout like that you should really be using a responsive design, rather than switching on user agent.

Comment: Note also that modifying settings is not thread safe and should not be done on a per-request basis, and TEMPLATE_DIRS was removed in 1.9.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  I would try what you said if I don't find a way to fix what I already have. But it really puzzles me that the code works in development but doesn't work in production o_o